# Redocly CLI command not found

Tags: zsh, redocly

I am trying to use Redocly CLI to split an OpenAPI definition file.

It was working last night but doesn't work this morning.

When I try to run a redocly command, for example:

```
redocly lint openapi.yaml
```

the output I get is:

```
zsh: command not found: redocly
```

Redocly CLI is installed globally.

I tried to install it again.

This is the command I used as shown in the Redocly documentation:

```
npm install @redocly/cli -g
```

And the output in the terminal is:

```
changed 256 packages, and audited 257 packages in 10s

31 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Any assistance would be helpful.